# Next.js custom hook for client side and prevent "did not match server/client" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

How to use the custom hook `useCustomHook()` in Next.js and prevent the `did not match server/client` error without using `useEffect()`? Like when using `swr` for example.

`useData()` stores data on the client side (context + localStorage).
I am trying to create a static site with some data provided by the user.

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [{ data }, dispatch] = useData()

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { // Client side
    return { data: data }
  }

  return { data: undefined }
}

export default function Page() {
  const { data } = useCustomHook()

  if (!data) {
    return <div>No data...</div>
  }

  return <div>Data {data.foobar}</div>
}
```

Context provider (`<DataProvider>` @ `_app.js`)

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from 'react'

const DataStateContext = createContext()

const initialState = {
  data: {},
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`)
  }
}

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const localState = initialState

  // Get the data from localStorage
  try {
    localState.data = localStorage.getItem('data')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))
      : null
  } catch (err) {}

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, localState)

  return (
    <DataStateContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </DataStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useData = () => useContext(DataStateContext)
```

Will result in `Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "No data..." Client: "Data "` when I reload the page.

But when I use `useSWR` I can reload the page without getting an error. Also the request is done only on the client side, server side `data` is just undefined (server doesn't make a request at all). How does this work? I have checked the code from swr, but I don't get it.

```
import useSWR from "swr";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/swr",
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) return "An error has occurred.";
  if (!data) return "Loading...";
  return (
    <div>{data.description}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code from your **useCustomContext** too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to memoize the return value in combination with `useEffect()` in your hook, that will also prevent multiple renders.

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [{ data }, dispatch] = useData()
  const [clientData, setClientData] = useState()

  const hasWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasWindow) {
      setClientData(data)
    }
  }, [hasWindow, data])

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      data: clientData,
    }),
    [clientData]
  )

  return value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't wanted to use `useEffect` because of rerender, but yeah, I have to use it and it doesn't rerender =) Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `hasWindow` might be redundant since useEffect only runs on the client and will always return true.